# Como pegar o tipo (class) de uma lista em groovy

Tags: java, groovy

Tenho o código abaixo:

```
Set<String> list
```

Como saber o tipo dessa lista? No caso seria `java.lang.String`

Comment: Não sou um especialista em Groovy (bem longe de ser). Mas considerando que a JVM implementa [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), é bem provável que não seja possível que tu obtenhas o type parameter de um tipo genérico (a não ser que tu mesmo guardes a informação de tipo de uma outra forma).

Comment: Conseguir resolver agora através desse link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list como groovy é um "java turbinado, porém dinâmica" deu certinho o código